# Cannot start openELEC on Raspberry Pi 3B+

Tags: boot-issues, pi-3b+, openelec, crash

I've tried a whole bunch of media center systems for my fresh RaspberryPi 3B+. The most interesting one for me is openELEC, but unfortunately it is the only one I can't seem to successfully run - neither version 8.0.4 nor version 7.0.1.

I'd love to upload a photo, but am not yet allowed to do this, here, so I decribe it: Right after powering on the device I see a square of color gradients and a lightning symbol like this:

```
Red - Yellow       [Yellow Lightning]
 |      |
Blue - Cyan
```

This is where booting stops. Neither keyboard nor mouse nor ethernet seems to be powered on and therefore the system doesn't react on any input. Only the red LED on the device blinks irregularly.

I came upon some articles warning of a set of non-working SD cards and a  [table with them, here](https://www.elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards), where I couldn't find any exact match with the ones I have, but similar cards would work according to the table. For the sake of completeness, this is all information I have about my SD cards:

- Panasonic microSDHC Class 4, 16 GB, E316G1236 TPSPM20930325 UE2IA004714 (nothing similar found)
- SanDisk microSDHC Class 4, 8 GB, MMBTR08GUBCA-ME I CYE161GA 122 (many similar are OK)

Furthermore, I also tried disconnecting peripherals and another power supply - to no avail.

**Has anyone had the same problems and found a solution?**

Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't believe the OpenElec images have been updated for the Pi3B+ yet - hence the rainbow screen.

Comment: try libreElec instead?

Comment: Just to clarify other comments the "rainbow square" is a symptom of an out of date kernel/firmware. You could try `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel` to update BUT this needs to be run on an older model which boots.

Comment: or try libreELEC - it works with 3B+

Comment: @CoderMike: I read something like "same image for pi 2 and 3", but I may have missed the Pi3B+ fact.

Comment: @Milliways: I couldn't test this, but good point.

Comment: @JaromandaX: I tried libreELEC now and it finally works. Thanks. I'll accept this as an answer.

Comment: I didn't post it as an answer :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, as of today, 8th January 2019, OpenELEC does not "support" the Raspberry Pi 3B+

[LibreELEC](https://libreelec.tv/) on the other hand does. It's a very similar Kodi implementation to OpenELEC, but seems to be more frequent in its releases

Comment: today 10 December 2019 and still there is no support for anyone who is like me jump to libreElec

Comment: @MohammedHousseynTaleb - are you saying OpenElec still doesn't support the 3B+? LibreELEC is far better supported anyway

Comment: yes yesterday I used the latest stable disk image of openelec on my brand new rpi3b+, and yes is not working, libreelec is good it worked but infortunatly for me I faced some issue with my screen the bug is well known and I m waiting for a fix release by libreelec